# Remove or edit item from Python queue

Tags: python, queue

I have a Python queue in which I add items in a thread like so

```
import queue
import threading

_myQueue = queue.Queue()

threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = _myQueue.get()
        # Do something with this item
        _myQueue.task_done()

def add_item(item):
    _myQueue.put(item)
```

My question is am I able to edit or delete items from this queue while my worker thread is doing something between _myQueue.get() and _myQueue.task_done():

```
item = _myQueue.get()
# Do something with this item
_myQueue.task_done()
```

For example if an item is 'cancelled' and no longer needs processed.

Comment: I guess every question needs a downvoter but I think its interesting. You certainly can do a `_myQueue.get()` in any piece of code safely, which would cancel that action. But you'll only get the next item in the list. Are you wanting to select which item to cancel? That's a more difficult question.

Comment: I don't want to cancel the current item that's being processed. I want to check the queue for a specific item and cancel it (Remove it from the queue)  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have full control over the class definition of the queued items, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `queue.Queue` to effectively implement a queue with random access:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

_myQueue = OrderedDict()

def worker():
    while True:
        item, _ = _myQueue.popitem(last=False)
        # Do something with this item

def add_item(item):
    _myQueue[item] = 1

def delete_item(item):
    del _myQueue[item]
```

If the item objects are not hashable, you'll just have to identify them by certain keys, such as an incremental number instead.

Comment: Interesting but the docs don't mention a `last` parameter and it fails on my 3.8.5. `popitem` is LIFO, not what you want on a task queue.

Comment: @tdelaney Are you sure you are reading the documentation of `collections.OrderedDict`, rather than `dict`? Please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem

Comment: @tdelaney Oops my bad. I accidentally instantiated `_myQueue` as a dict in the code example above. Corrected it to become an `OrderedDict` object now, which does support the `last` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have full control over the class definition of the queued items, you can add a flag as an instance attribute to indicate whether the item is cancelled, so that the worker can skip a cancelled item when it's dequeued:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cancelled = False

    def cancel():
        self.cancelled = True

def worker():
    while True:
        item = _myQueue.get()
        if item.cancelled:
            continue
        # Do something with this item
        _myQueue.task_done()

# call item.cancel() to mark an item as cancelled
```

Comment: How do I actually access the item from the queue to mark it as cancelled?

Comment: Well how do you identify which item to cancel in the first place? You must have a separate container object (such as a list, a dict or a set)  that keeps track of all the items, right? So once you decide to cancel an item you obtain from the said container, you call the `cancel` method of the item to cancel it.

Comment: A potential problem is that since the set-cancel and test-cancel operations are not atomic, the setter can't be sure that the operation was cancelled. Add to that there isn't a way to know that the task is in progress. That's fine if the design is best-effort, but more controls may need to be added.

Comment: There is another function that gets activated on a database callback, so in that i would need to access the _myQueue, look for the specific item and set cancelled=True

Comment: So how can I access and 'edit' an item in the queue? from another function?